# ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> undefined method `gender' for #

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
   <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

         <%= f.label :gender %>
      <%= f.text_field :gender, class: 'form-control' %>
```

so I add `gender` attribute to `users` db

`rails generate migration AddGenderToUsers gender:string
 rake db:migrate
rails server`

Then all pages are not accessible .

```
ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError
```

Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development

I don't know why as it worked before .
I tried to  `rake db:migrate` ,but it didnt work .

Comment: did you run the migration with RAILS_ENV=development as per the error message?

Comment: rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development

Comment: @vishwas nahar not working

Comment: @margo  u mean rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development  ?

Comment: RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake db:migrate

Comment: @vishwas nahar `RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake db:migrate` no this syntax

Comment: Did this work for you ?

Comment: @vishwas nahar undefined syntax ,it replied

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141277/discussion-between-vishwas-nahar-and-monchhichi).